# Radeon Hd2600xt to mid 2010 27" iMac under TDM

Tags: display, imac

I want to use a mid-2010 27" im iMac as a monitor for a 2007 mac pro fitted with a Radeon Hd2600xt.

My question is a simple one: Is a DVI to MDP cable the way to go to achieve this, and should it be done in TDM?

Is there another way to achieve same? - Via firewire for example?

Strange to slave the imac to an older mac pro perhaps, but that's what I need.

I have read a lot of the threads about using imacs as monitors, but there is scant info on what cable to use in my particular circumstances.
Thanks :)